# UITableView and UINavigationBar customization confusion. Any advice on how this was done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

Here is a part of the AirBnB app I would like built.

[image]

Here are the 3 questions that I'm in need of advice on.

1. How do i get a cell on a UITableView to act like the [ MORE FILTERS ] button? The button seems to act like a UITableView cell that always stay at the top. YET, it fades away just before going out of scope. **Is this even a tableViewCell?**[image]
2. The view [ARRIVES | DEPARTS]. What view is this on a UITableView? When the tableView is scrolled all the way to the top it connects seamlessly with the [MORE FILTERS] button making it seem like its one view. But when the tableView starts scrolling, the [MORE FILTERS] button can be seen sliding over it as it fades away.

   [image]
3. What is the [SHOW FILTERS] button? Is it a UINavigationItem titleView property or some separate view? As the table scrolls up it can be seen attaching itself to the UINavigationBar in a fade transition. At first i thought it was a just a UINavigationBarItem, but I do not know how to add items **under** the title of the bar. Any clarification on what this is or how can be accomplished?

[image]

I have already looked at [Apple's Example on customized UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html), but it doesnt provide any clues to accomplish this. Any help appreciated

Comment: you can easily customise [VGParallaxHeader](https://github.com/stoprocent/VGParallaxHeader) to achieve this effect I believe.

Answer (score 4):

just like you did, when I came across an application like this one which has cool UI effects and animation, I would like to analyse and if possible try to do the same effect by myself, so that I could get innovations as well as knowledges.

Let's analyse it first, at the meantime you will probably find all the answers. I just drew a graph which shows the UI hierarchy of the screen, of course this hierarchy is based on my analysis, I cannot guarantee that the hierarchy is 100% correct.

[image: Hierarchy]

I will do a bit of explanations here. From top to bottom:
1. The `Navigation Bar(Red)`, just a opaque navigation bar, nothing special;
2. The `Show Filters View(Purple)` is a view which anchors to the bottom of the `Navigation Bar(Red)`, and it is hided when the screen launches. **Please note that this view is not a subview of `Arrives & Departs View(Blue)`**. It is added directly to the view controller's root view. Which means `Purple` and `Blue` are siblings;
3. The `Arrives & Departs View(Blue)`, nothing special;
4. The `More Filters View(Green)`, nothing special;
5. The `Table View(Orange)`, nothing special;
So from my analysis, `Purple`, `Blue`, `Green` and `Orange` are all siblings.

Now let's move on to the fancy UI effects and animations. The trick here is you need to observe the change of the table view's `contentOffset` (I recommend to do it in the scroll view's delegate - `scrollViewDidScroll`), and move, hide or show the views accordingly. There are four stages:
1. The initial stage, like the graph above.
2. The `Blue` starts fading out, `Green` moves up as the finger moves, `Orange` increases its height. (Purple is still at the same position and hided, I just removed it from the graph in order to make it clearer);

[image: Stage Two]

3. `Blue` totally faded out, `Green` starts fading out and `Purple` starts fading in. `Orange` is still doing the same - increasing its height;

[image]

4. `Green` totally faded out, `Purple` totally faded in and `Orange` increases its height to fill the screen and then anchors to the bottom of `Purple`.

[image]

Comment: increasing the height of the tableView in ScrollViewDidScroll will not be pretty, also the content offset will be zero in step 1 to 4 - that doesnt make sense.

Comment: I propose a small change : The tableview(Yellow) is always anchored to the bottom of the nav bar, but with an empty cell with the required height. that ought to simplify things.

Comment: Question: What sort of view would the [SHOW FILTERS] button be then? I am not sure how a normal uiview can be anchored to the bottom of a UINavigationBar..

Comment: If you are using frame based layout, then just set the frame to `CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, width, height)` then add it to the view controller's root view - `[self.view addSubview:showFilters]`; If you are using Auto Layout, then you need to add a top constraints between `showFilters` and `self.view`

Answer (score 3):

1. The [MORE FILTERS] button does appear to be a cell of the UITableView. Since it is a different type of cell than the other cells containing the UIImageView and the UILabels using a different identifier you can tell the cell to fade away with an animation. [Try this link for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409405/swift-fading-cells-in-uitableview)
2. The [ARRIVES | DEPARTS] seems to be its own view. I believe that this and the tableview are both part of a UIScrollView. This is the reason that it seamlessly disappears when the [MORE FILTERS] cell scrolls up towards it.
3. The [SHOW FILTERS] button could just be a part of the navigation bar. When the scrollView finishes scrolling the navigation bar can be extended. However, it is also possible that the button is in a view of its own and is hidden until the scrollview finishes scrolling. Either way should be possible but I would recommend putting it in its own view rather than attaching it to the navigation bar.